# Angular Custom Form Validation and Directives

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, angularjs, customvalidator

I have a custom validation directive that I had attributed to the form

```
<form myValidations>

app.directive('myValidations', function(){
return{
    //require: 'ngModel', note its commented out

    link: function(s,e,a,ctrl){//note the emphasis on the ctrl


    }
}
});
```

now how would I grip this ctrl.$parsers if I don't have the 'require: ngModel' to do it for me.

could i find an element and then call its ng-model in some function to return an ng-model-controller? so that I can #$parsers from there?

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle with your relevant code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering your question, you can call `angular.element('elementSelector').controller('ngModel')`. It would return the ngModel the same way a `require` would.

The question is: **if you are creating a new directive, why not use its require feature?** There are big chances that you are not using the right solution for your problem. So a bit more of code would give us the opportunity to further enlighten your question.

Comment: Thanks, you are awesome, Well, I need to contain everything inside one validator directive, and so I would need to perform $parsers on a multiple number of ng-models, so one require I would assume could only perform .controller on the whole form which I attributed the diretive to. Thanks.

Comment: Does your validation consider all fields together? Or is it the same for all fields individually? For the first case, you can create a directive that applies to the `form` and use [name property](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:form) to expose all children controls. For the latter, you can create an agnostic directive that adds a [`$parser`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngModel.NgModelController) to the element it applies to.

Comment: individually, I am checking for individual inputs, which need controller on their own. For this task I was asked to namespace the entire validation into one directive.

Comment: A second question is, is there a way I can grep the ng:show param "form.username.$error" from controller or directive?

Comment: also adding on to your answer, One problem i've noticed is that if you don't import jquery, jqlite will not be able to do .find (id and class) and .controller properly if the form consist of complex divs with select radio and inputs. I believe you are a big expert on angular, could you please verify this?

Comment: It's possible to bind `ng-show` to your validation, but this should be a separated question. There is an example [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms). Read the [guide](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide), [tutorial](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/) adm [API](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/).